# How can I sign and package Xamarin.Forms application using Visual Studio 2015?

Tags: android, xamarin

I'm trying to publish my Xamarin.Forms application on Google Play.
How can I `sign` and `package` Xamarin.Forms application using `Visual Studio 2015`?

Note : I don't have Android Studio.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Signing and publishing Xamarin.Forms project (Android, since you have tagged Android only) is the same as signing and publishing Xamarin.Android application.

[Link to Tutorial for Sign an Android Application using Xamarin](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/deployment,_testing,_and_metrics/publishing_an_application/part_2_-_signing_the_android_application_package/)

[Link to Tutorial for Publish an Android Application to Play Store using Xamarin](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/deployment,_testing,_and_metrics/publishing_an_application/part_3_-_publishing_an_application_on_google_play/)